# Unit test delegate action is called

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, delegates, nunit

I have a Dictionary that I am using to avoid writing big if statements. It maps an enum to an action. It looks like this:

```
 var decisionMapper = new Dictionary<int, Action>
                             {
                                 {
                                     (int) ReviewStepType.StandardLetter,
                                     () =>  
                           caseDecisionService.ProcessSendStandardLetter(aCase)
                                     },
                                 {
                                     (int) ReviewStepType.LetterWithComment,
                                     () => 
                          caseDecisionService.ProcessSendStandardLetter(aCase)
                                     },
                                 {
                                     (int) ReviewStepType.BespokeLetter,
                                     () =>              
                          caseDecisionService.ProcessSendBespokeLetter(aCase)

                                     },
                                 {
                                     (int) ReviewStepType.AssignToCaseManager,
                                     () => 
                          caseDecisionService.ProcessContinueAsCase(aCase)
                                     },
                             };
```

then I call it like this in my method:

```
     decisionMapper[(int) reviewDecisionRequest.ReviewStepType]();
```

My question is **how can I unit test these mappings?** 
(I am using Nunit and c# 4.0)

How can I assert that when I call my decisionMapper - that 1 is equal to the call -caseDecisionService.ProcessSendStandardLetter(aCase).

Thanks very much.

Comment: What type is ReviewStepType? Enum? If you can Enum.GetValues() (and then cast each one to int).

Comment: hi thanks, yes its an enum. how would that work with the test? i want to know that i have done my mappings correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping with this.  This was what I did in the end.

I mocked the Action Service call, then invoked the dictionary's value, then called AssertWasCalled / AssertWasNotCalled.  Like this:

```
        mapper[(int) ReviewStepType.StandardLetter].Invoke();
        caseDecisionService.AssertWasCalled(c => c.ProcessSendStandardLetter(aCase),
                                            options => options.IgnoreArguments());
        caseDecisionService.AssertWasNotCalled(c =>  
                                               c.ProcessSendBespokeLetter(aCase),
                                               options => options.IgnoreArguments());
        caseDecisionService.AssertWasNotCalled(c => 
                                               c.ProcessContinueAsCase(aCase),
                                               options => options.IgnoreArguments());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare anonymous delegates (see [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/489518/creating-two-delegate-instances-to-the-same-anonymous-method-are-not-equal) link). You have to use a little bit of reflection to check the `Method` property of the `Action` delegate. It has to match the `MethodInfo` of the `caseDecisionService` method that should be invoked. For example (You may rewrite to use a function to make code shorter):

```
MethodInfo methodToCall =
   decisionMapper[(int)ReviewStepType.StandardLetter].Method;

MethodInfo expectedMethod =
   typeof(CaseDecisionService).GetType().GetMethod("ProcessSendStandardLetter");

Assert.AreSame(expectedMethod, methodToCall);
```

Comment: thanks for this. Although the ".Method" returns me the methodinfo of the service method in which the mapper is initialized. Not the specific Action method info. So the assert is always false at the moment

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping. I got it working like this in the end. I mocked the Action (caseDecisionService), called Invoke on the dictionary, then used assertwascalled/assertwasnotcalled. Like this :

mapper[(int) ReviewStepType.StandardLetter].Invoke();
        caseDecisionService.AssertWasCalled(c => c.ProcessSendStandardLetter(aCase),                                           options => options.IgnoreArguments());  caseDecisionService.AssertWasNotCalled(c => c.ProcessSendBespokeRpcLetter(aCase),                                                   options => options.IgnoreArguments());

Comment: Good idea, post it as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't bother writing a unit test which directly checks which action is invoked in each case.

Assuming this dictionary is part of a larger system, I'd write one test which goes through each of the Dictionary actions via whatever class *contains* the Dictionary. I want to check my code gives me outcomes I expect (the outcome of calling `ProcessSendStandardLetter()` or `ProcessSendBespokeLetter()`, for example); I'm less interested in checking exactly how it does it.